# Android and the NDK/librarys

Tags: android, c++, c, audio, android-ndk

I have now admitted defeat that you cannot use/build a good audio pitch function without using the NDK. Now my question is does anyone know of any good pitch changing code either in a library or some source code for the NDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at the MicDroid app that does auto-tune, sources available on GitHub: https://github.com/intervigilium/MicDroid

some more info here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=721388

Comment: my mistake its actually the tempo I need to change, but that is an awesome answer